# Singularities at infinity and equality of functions on the integers

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a problem with an exercise concerning singularities at infinity

> Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a domain such that $\mathbb{C} \setminus U$ is compact, and let $f: U \to \mathbb{C}$. be holomorphic.
>
> We say that $z_0=\infty$ is a removable singularity / pole of order $m$ / essential singularity of $f$ iff $\xi_0$ is one for $g(\xi)=f \left(\frac{1}{\xi}\right)$.
>
> a) Show that any entire function with a removable singularity at $z_0=\infty$ is a polynomial of order $m$.
>
> b) Let $f_1,f_2: U \to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic with removable singularities at $z_0=\infty$ such that $f_1(k)=f_2(k)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z} \cap U$. Show that $f_1=f_2$.

I wanted to prove statement b) using the following theorem.

> Let $D \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a domain (an open, connected set). Let $J$ be a subset of $D$ having an accumulation point $a \in D$. Let $h_1,h_2: D \to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic. If $h_1=h_2$ on $J$ then $h_1=h_2$ on $D$.

Since the functions $f_1, f_2$ are holomorphic with removable singularities at $z_0=\infty$ the functions $g_1, g_2$ defined as $g_i(\xi)=f_i \left(\frac{1}{\xi}\right), \ i \in \{1,2\}$ have removable singularities at $0$. Then we can extend $g_1, g_2$ to $\{0\}$ such that the extensions are holomorphic on $U \cup \{0\}$. Now define $J=\{ \frac{1}{k} \ | \ k \in \mathbb{Z} \cap U \}$. Then $0$ is an accumulation point of $J$. Then

$$
g_1(\frac{1}{k})=f_1(k)=f_2(k)=g_2(\frac{1}{k})
$$

for all $k \in \mathbb{Z} \cap U$. So $g_1, g_2$ agree on $J$. By the theorem I have $g_1=g_2$ on $U$. But this implies $f_1=f_2$. My problem is that I do not think that $U \cup \{0\}$ is a domain so the theorem does not apply. Can this proof be salvaged?

Comment: Your second line is not complete. But yes, your proof can be salvaged. It's not $U\cup \{0\},$ it's $\{1/z:z\in U\} \cup \{0\}.$

Comment: What zhw is referring to at the start of their comment is "Let $U\subset \Bbb C$ be a domain such that $\Bbb C\setminus U$". $\Bbb C\setminus U$ is a set, not a condition. What is it that is required to hold for  $\Bbb C\setminus U$? I'm guessing if you check, the condition will be $\Bbb C\setminus U$ *is bounded*. And if $U$ completely surrounds $\infty$, what can you say about $\dfrac 1U$ and $0$?

Comment: $\mathbb{C} \setminus U$ is compact and therefore indeed closed and bounded. Then $\frac{1}{U}$ and $0$ are contained in $\mathbb{C} \setminus U$. Moreover I can conclude that for any point in $\frac{1}{U} \cup \{0\}$ I can find an open neighborhood $\{x \ | \ |x|< \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\} $ with $\varepsilon$  being the bound of $\mathbb{C} \setminus U$ so that every element of  $\frac{1}{U} \cup \{0\}$ is contained in that neighborhood.